# Java interceptor priority

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, annotations, interceptor

This might be a trivial question for many of you but I swear I couldn't find the answer anywhere else:

let's say I have a class like this

```
@Interceptors(Interceptor1.class)
class myClass
{
    @Interceptors({Interceptor2.class, Interceptors3.class})
    public void myMethod() {...}
}
```

when myMethod is called which interceptors are executed and in which order?

Interceptor2, Interceptor3
or
Interceptor1, Interceptor2, Interceptor3
or
Interceptor2, Interceptor3, Interceptor1?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from [Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/EJB3_Interceptors.html)

By default the ordering of interceptors when invoking a method are

- External interceptors
- Default interceptors, if present
- Class interceptors, if present
- Method interceptors, if present
- Interceptor method on the bean class (using @AroundInvoke)

Within each group (default, class, method) the order of the interceptors are from left to right as defined in the @Interceptors annotation, and then the XML interceptors.